# Javascript loop indexing issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Here's the HTML

```
<li class="carousel-btn-wrapper">
  <div class="progressButton">
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <button class="videoCaroselButton">Welcome</button>
</li>
<li class="carousel-btn-wrapper">
  <div class="progressButton">
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <button class="videoCaroselButton">Video Name</button>
</li>
<li class="carousel-btn-wrapper">
  <div class="progressButton">
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <button class="videoCaroselButton">Another Video Name</button>
</li>
```

I am trying to add a number in the p tag that is a child of the .progressButton. I need the number to increase with every p tag. I'm having issues with my javascript loop. I assume the issue is in the way .text(buttonNumber[]); is indexing. How do I solve this?

```
var videoSrcArray = ['url.com/adf', 'url.com/asf', 'url.com/sdf', 'url.com/asdf','url.com/asdfl']
var buttonNumber = "";
var i;
for (i = 1; i < videoSrcArray.length - 1; i++) {
  buttonNumber += i ;
  $('.progressButton').children('p').text(buttonNumber[1]);
}
```

Comment: First if you want to add a number why did you initialized buttonNumber as String? And second what do you mean by calling a string with []?

Comment: Are you getting 1 then 12 then 123 and so on?

Comment: `buttonNumber` is being initialized as `""`. Adding an integer to it will result in concatenated strings.

Comment: I'm getting 1 as if it is being concatinated or 123456789101112131415, since there are 15 items in the real array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually don't need `buttonNumber` at all. Delete it (lines 2 and 5)
and then change:

```
$('.progressButton').children('p').text(buttonNumber[1]);
```

to:

```
$('.progressButton').children('p').eq(i-1).text(i);
```

Comment: Doing so gets the length of the array only. So each p tag has "15" in it since that is the total number of items within the array.

Comment: i would recommend one more edit. ".eq(i-1).text(i)" so it the number starts at 1 rather than 0. But thank you.

Comment: ah my bad, I didn't notice your loop started at 1 haha

Answer (score 0):

Try init buttonNumber as 0.
Then, use var to init the i of your for loop, and then use buttonNumber.toString() instead of buttonNumber[]